# Suppress error message No entity found for query

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

I use this code to get single row result:

```
@Override
    public PaymentTransactions transactionByUnique_Id(String unique_id) throws Exception {

        String hql = "select e from " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " e where e.unique_id = :unique_id";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql).setParameter("unique_id", unique_id);
        PaymentTransactions paymentTransaction = (PaymentTransactions) query.getSingleResult();
        return paymentTransaction;
    }
```

But when I don't have matching row I get exception:

```
14:25:41,736 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
```

How I can suppress that exception and just to continue code execution?

Comment: Call getResultList(), and return its first element if it's present. Also, please, respect the Java naming conventions, and use a TypedQuery.

Comment: How should I change the code in order to use TypedQuery?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-

Comment: Basic java is catching an exception and returning a different result from your method based on that. Nothing to do with the JPA API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just throw and catch javax.persistence.NoResultException exception and continue your code execution.

Possible duplicate of [How to continue program execution even after throwing exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412995/how-to-continue-program-execution-even-after-throwing-exception)

Answer (score 1):

Just update way to logging:

```
    log4j.logger.javax.persistence=WARN
```